# Mapping complex stored procedure with code first approach

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

Is it possible with Entity Framework code-first approach to map already created stored procedures?

For example I have a complex stored procedure and I want to map it with code first approach.

I will run the script for creating stored procedure using migration so the procedure will always available but how to map it with code first approach?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no built-in support to map the stored procedure in code-first. You have to manually call the procedure though you can map the results of the procedure using `ObjectContext`'s `Translate` method.

E.g.

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    // If using Code First we need to make sure the model is built before we open the connection 
    // This isn't required for models created with the EF Designer 
    db.Database.Initialize(force: false); 

    // Create a SQL command to execute the sproc 
    var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand(); 
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetAllBlogsAndPosts]"; 

    try 
    { 
        db.Database.Connection.Open(); 
        // Run the sproc  
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

        // Read Blogs from the first result set 
        var blogs = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db) 
            .ObjectContext 
            .Translate<Blog>(reader, "Blogs", MergeOption.AppendOnly);    

        foreach (var item in blogs) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name); 
        }         

        // Move to second result set and read Posts 
        reader.NextResult(); 
        var posts = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db) 
            .ObjectContext 
            .Translate<Post>(reader, "Posts", MergeOption.AppendOnly); 

        foreach (var item in posts) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(item.Title); 
        } 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        db.Database.Connection.Close(); 
    } 
}
```

You can also map the stored procedure that returns more complex type, if you're using an `.EDMX` file. See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx) for more details.

**Note:** you can add T4 template to add the custom mapping to add the custom stored procedure mapping every time the `.EDMX` is generated.

Comment: Is it possible to have edmx for code first approach?

Comment: Possible in a way. With the [Entity Frameworks Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) installed you can right-click the context in your solution view, click on "Entity Framework", then select "View Entity Data Model". This will generate the EDMX from your dbcontext class.

Comment: Doesn't support Table Per Hierarchy types.  For example, Tranlate<BaseType> throws an exception saying it can't instantiate the abstract base type. It also, apparently, doesn't take custom column mappings into account, so it really cannot load entities from a sproc.